# my tailwind media query utility is dysfunctional

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

Using Tailwind I set an element to apply the 'flex-col' utility by default but 'flex-row' utility on small devices, so 'sm:flex-row'. But it applies the sm flex utility by default instead of the 'flex-col' I'd set. Please, what can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind uses a [mobile first](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#mobile-first) breakpoint system

> What this means is that unprefixed utilities (like `uppercase`) take effect on all screen sizes, while prefixed utilities (like `md:uppercase`) only take effect at the specified breakpoint and above.

Therefore you should change applied variants into `sm:flex-col` (no need to add `flex-row` class as it is default flex direction)

Comment: this was very helpful, although I had fixed the problem before seeing this reply but I solved it in a similar way. Thank you!